# how to avoid lag when i set setOffscreenLimit for viewPager

Tags: android

I need retain state of previous fragments in viewpager. So am setting offScreenLimit for viewPager. When I set OffScreenLimit loading of page is lags.

Am dynamically creating number of fragments. These is how i initializing fragments.

```
public class DynamicFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
    public static Map map;
    private static DynamicFragment f;
    private JSONArray radiodata;
    Window window;
    private String[] radioName;
    public static RadioGroup radioGroup;
    DynamicViews dynamicviews;
    Page2Info[] page2Infos = new Page2Info[10];
    private int dynamicViewId;
    View rootView;
    private HashMap<Integer, Page2Info> infomap;
    private static HashMap hashMap;
    static String selitem;
    private static Spinner spinner;
    static EditText myEditTxt;
    private JSONArray spinnerdata;
    private View view;


    static Context mContext;
    private int maxLength = 10;
    boolean _areLecturesLoaded = false;
    private int data;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    MyPageAdapter myPageAdapter ;


    public static final DynamicFragment newInstance(String message) {
        f = new DynamicFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }
/*

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        PageViewActivity pageViewActivity = new PageViewActivity();
        List<Fragment> fragments = pageViewActivity.getFragments();

        myPageAdapter = new PageViewActivity.MyPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),fragments);

    }
*/



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout1, container, false);


        ImageView dynamicImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_image);

        map = HomeFrag.dynamicPagesHashMap;
        dynamicviews = new DynamicViews();
        mContext = getActivity();
        infomap = new HashMap<Integer, Page2Info>();
        hashMap = new HashMap();
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout);
        LinearLayout topLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toplayout);


        Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            int id = (int) pair.getKey();
            DynamicPages dynamicPages[] = (DynamicPages[]) pair.getValue();
            String headings = dynamicPages[id].getHeadings();
            String properties = dynamicPages[id].getProperties();
            String clientData = dynamicPages[id].getClientData();
            String detractor = dynamicPages[id].getDetractor();
            String passive = dynamicPages[id].getPassive();
            String promoter = dynamicPages[id].getPromoter();
            String categories = dynamicPages[id].getCategories();
            String scale = dynamicPages[id].getScale();
            String scaleType = dynamicPages[id].getScaletype();
            String questionnaire = dynamicPages[id].getQuestionnaire();
            String commentBox = dynamicPages[id].getComment();
            String pageName = dynamicPages[id].getPageName();
            String listParam = null;
            String category = dynamicPages[id].getCategory();
            String dataclient = dynamicPages[id].getDataclient();
            String paramViews  = dynamicPages[id].getParamViews();


            if(pageName.equalsIgnoreCase("parameterizedpage")){
                listParam =  dynamicPages[id].getList();

            }




            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Fragment" + id + "")) {


                switch (pageName){


                    case "welcomepage" :
                        LayoutInflater layoutWelcome = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayWelcomePage displayWelcomePage = new DisplayWelcomePage(layoutWelcome);
                        view =  displayWelcomePage.createWelcomePage(getActivity(),container,headings,properties);
                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;

                    case "personalinfo":
                        Constants.REQUIRED_FIELD = "On";
                        LayoutInflater layoutPersonalInfo = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayPersonalInfo displayPersonalInfo = new DisplayPersonalInfo(layoutPersonalInfo);
                        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                        displayPersonalInfo.setResources(getResources());
                        view = displayPersonalInfo.createInfoPage(getActivity(),container,clientData,headings,properties);
                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;

                    case "scale":
                        Constants.SCALE_REQUIRED = "On";
                        LayoutInflater layoutScale = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        if (scaleType.equalsIgnoreCase("NPS")) {
                            scale = "0";
                            DisplayNpsScale displayNpsScale = new DisplayNpsScale(layoutScale);
                            view = displayNpsScale.CreateScale(scale, container, getContext(),headings,properties);
                            displayNpsScale.setResource(getResources());
                            topLayout.addView(view);
                            break;

                        } else {
                            DisplayCsatScale displayCsatScale = new DisplayCsatScale(layoutScale);
                            view = displayCsatScale.CreateScale(scale, container, getContext(),headings,properties);
                            displayCsatScale.setResources(getResources());
                            topLayout.addView(view);
                            break;
                        }

                    case "questionnaire":
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_DETRACTOR = detractor;
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_PROMOTER = promoter;
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_PASSIVE = passive;


                        // Constants.CAMPAIGN_DATA_CAT = category;
                        LayoutInflater layoutList = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayExpanList displayExpanList = new DisplayExpanList(layoutList);
                        view = displayExpanList.createList(container, getContext(),headings,properties,category,dataclient,paramViews);
                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;

                    case "questionnaire2":
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_DETRACTOR = detractor;
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_PROMOTER = promoter;
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_PASSIVE = passive;


                        // Constants.CAMPAIGN_DATA_CAT = category;
                        LayoutInflater layoutList2 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayExpanList2 displayExpanList2 = new DisplayExpanList2(layoutList2);
                        view = displayExpanList2.createList(container, getContext(),headings,properties,category,dataclient,paramViews);
                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;
                    case "questionnaire3":
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_DETRACTOR = detractor;
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_PROMOTER = promoter;
                        Constants.CAMPAIGN_PASSIVE = passive;


                        // Constants.CAMPAIGN_DATA_CAT = category;
                        LayoutInflater layoutList3 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayExpanList3 displayExpanList3 = new DisplayExpanList3(layoutList3);
                        view = displayExpanList3.createList(container, getContext(),headings,properties,category,dataclient,paramViews);
                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;
                    case "commentbox":
                        LayoutInflater layoutComment = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayCommentBox displayCommentBox = new DisplayCommentBox(layoutComment);
                        view = displayCommentBox.createCommentBox(container, getContext(), headings, properties);
                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;

                    case "thankyoupage":
                        Constants.THANKYOUPAGE_HEADING = headings;
                        Constants.THANKYOUPAGE_PROPERTIES = properties;
                        break;
                    case "CRM" :
                        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayCRM displayCRM = new DisplayCRM(layoutInflater);
                        view = displayCRM.createCRM(container,getContext());
                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;

                    case "parameterizedpage":
                        LayoutInflater layoutParamPage = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                        DisplayParameterizedViews displayParameterizedViews = new DisplayParameterizedViews(layoutParamPage);
                        displayParameterizedViews.setResources(getResources());
                        window = getActivity().getWindow();
                        displayParameterizedViews.setWindow(getActivity().getWindow());
                        view = displayParameterizedViews.createParameterizedViews(container, getContext(), headings,listParam,properties,window );

                        topLayout.addView(view);
                        break;


                }


            }

        }


        //messageTextView.setText(message);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
}
```

The above code for initializing fragments.
Setting offScreenLimit here

```
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new CustomViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                   pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
            }

            if (pager.getCurrentItem() == Constants.NUM_PAGES - 2) {

                prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                videoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE
                );


            }
            if (pager.getCurrentItem() > 0 && pager.getCurrentItem() < Constants.NUM_PAGES - 2) {
                prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Lag is when moving from page2 to page3.

Comment: The lag can be due to many reasons. Can you share some code? How and where are you initializing your fragments?

Comment: Why do you set the limit only on that condition?